# How can I update image in listview in gridview format?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i update image in listview in gridview formate using folder path in asp.net in c#?

```
 protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      TextBox ApplicantIdTextBox = (TextBox)RadListView8.FindControl("ApplicantIdTextBox");
      FileUpload photoTextBox = (FileUpload)RadListView8.FindControl("photoTextBox");


      string fileName1 = Path.GetExtension(ApplicantIdTextBox + photoTextBox.FileName);
      string fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("ImageStorage/" + fileName1);
      tblPersonalInfo pi = new tblPersonalInfo();
      pi.photo = fileName1;
      photoTextBox.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

      dbcontext.AddTotblPersonalInfoes(pi);
      dbcontext.SaveChanges();
 }
```

But it show me error...What can i do?

> Server Error in '/HrPayRoll' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: On which line you got the error?

Comment: string fileName1 = Path.GetExtension(ApplicantIdTextBox + photoTextBox.FileName);  i got the error

Comment: @LutfunNahar You're using a `TextBox` object as though it's a `string`.  You probably meant to use `ApplicantIdTextBox.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite it something like this and then run it in debug mode and see what line the error is on.  You were trying to use `applicantIdTextBox` as a `string`, although I would have thought that would give a different error:

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox applicantIdTextBox = RadListView8.FindControl("ApplicantIdTextBox") as TextBox;
    FileUpload photoTextBox = RadListView8.FindControl("photoTextBox") as FileUpload;

    if ((applicantIdTextBox != null) && (photoTextBox != null))
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetExtension(applicantIdTextBox.Text + photoTextBox.FileName);
        string fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("ImageStorage/" + fileName);

        tblPersonalInfo personalInfo = new tblPersonalInfo();
        personalInfo.photo = fileName;

        photoTextBox.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

        dbcontext.AddTotblPersonalInfoes(personalInfo);
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: now problm is that, my image is update applicantid concate the filename... only file name is got & image is not show...plz help

Comment: @LutfunNahar have you stepped through the code in debug mode?  Try that and see if it's entering the main `if` block.

Comment: it does not enter the block..may be

Comment: @LutfunNahar if it doesn't enter the `if` block, then it possibly couldn't find either of the two web controls on your form.  In debug you should be able to see which one is null and investigate why the `FindControl` method is unable to find the control (maybe it's spelt wrong?).

Comment: in this code have no error but when i update image then file upload control take only file name so,, image isn't show